# Unique Id for all the entities from all repositories

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, doctrine-odm

In PHPCR (NoSQL) there is something like Uuid (it's something different than Id in the table, unique only for the single table) - the Id that is unique to all Documents (Entities) in the whole data base. It's of much help when e.g. using forms, because I can use Uuid without knowing the exact class of an entity, and still being able to access directly a related record just by:

```
$objectManager->find(null, $uuid);
```

I'd like to have a similar solution with the RDBMS in the Doctrine ORM, i.e. to find a record when knowing only its unique id (Uuid). Do anyone of you know about such a solution?

**From the PHPCR-ODM documentation:**

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types

> Each document can have a unique identifier for referencing it. While the uuid is also exposed as a read-only string property, the proper mapping for it is mapping it as UUID.

**UPDATE:**

Here are the Doctrine's sources:

From the general Doctrine common lib https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ObjectManager.php#L42

```
public function find($className, $id);
```

From the ORM https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L380

```
public function find($entityName, $id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
```

But I don't stick to find() method.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent `$entityManager->find()` method does not allow for the entity parameter to be null. So no, there is no way to do the same using the ORM.

I would surmise the reason for this is that document db's are quite different from relational databases. In a relational database you would need to query every table. To put it another way, using an ORM you would need to query every entity. With a document database, as far as I can tell, each document is a set whereas in a relational database sets are derived.

I hope that helps and makes sense. I've no experience with document databases. The method signature for `find()` in the ORM seems to explain it though.

Comment: Not necesserily to query every table. In fact, I already invented a solution, but I hoped there's such bundle (e.g. like there are bundles enhancing Doctrine capabilities) that already someone has written, otherwise I would have to write it by myself. My solution is quite simple: the Uuid for ORM may contain information about both, Id and the class, and could be a single string, e.g. hashed. As for other points, I updated my original message.